# How to convert QString containing an exponential number to double in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, double, precision, qstring

I want to convert `QString("3.285072743893E-04")` to `double` without compromising the precision.

When I use `QString::toDouble` the result is `0.000328507`.

I have read somewhere that it is just a matter of how the value is displayed.

Does that mean, that converting the value to `double`, `QString::toDouble` actually preserves its precision, i.e. that the precission of the returned value of type `double` is not compromised? And more importantly, if we process the data, do we need to worry about its precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of executing

```
QString s1 = "3.285072743893E-04";
double num = s1.toDouble(NULL);
QString s2 = QString::number(num, 'g', 20);
std::cout << s2.toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
```

on my setup (Qt 4.7.3) is:

```
0.00032850727438929998173
```

As you can see, the precision is retained for all but the last digit.

Comment: in fact precision is fully conserved as much as `double` type allows - 15-16 decimal digits. So when you take 17 significant digits `0.00032850727438929998` and round them to 16 digits you will have exactly same value as initially.